# Postgres 9.3 copy data from another table with relation

Tags: postgresql, replication, postgresql-9.3

Hi I have two tables in my database which is related, which is `forms` and `qa_forms`.

```
forms
->id
->name
-address
-phone
-calldatetime
```

and then `

```
qa_forms
->id
->forms_id
->name
->address
->phone
```

So the `qa_forms` is just the replicate of `forms` I already have data on both however I forgot to add `calldatetime` in my `qa_forms`. So what I did is i add new column on `qa_forms` which is `calldatetime`. As expected all the values will be null since I already have data before and this one is newly added, how can I get their respective `calldatetime` on `forms` on the fastest way I can do it? They have relation which is `forms.id = qa_forms.forms_id`.

Any query on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think something like this would work -- let me know if it doesn't

```
WITH forms_data AS (
  SELECT id, calldatetime FROM forms
) UPDATE qa_forms qf
  SET calldatetime = fd.calldatetime
  FROM forms_data fd
  WHERE qf.id = fd.id;
```

Edit (better version, suggested by dezso):

```
UPDATE qa_forms qf
SET calldatetime = f.calldatetime
FROM forms f
WHERE qf.id = f.id;
```

Comment: You can simply use `forms` in the `FROM` clause, it will work just as well.  In addition, if the `WHERE` of the `UPDATE` sepcified only a subset of `qa_forms`, the simpler version would be even faster.